# SQL Update for cases

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-update, inner-join, mariadb-10.4

I'm trying to update a column after I join two tables. If one column matches another I want to change another to 'W' and if it is already blank/NULL I want to leave it, otherwise I want to change it to 'L'. Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE user_games 
LEFT JOIN games ON user_games.game_key = games.game_id 
SET user_games.result = CASE 
                            WHEN user_games.pick = games.winner then 'W';
                            WHEN games.winner = NULL then NULL;
                            ELSE 'L';
                        END;
```

I'm getting this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

I'm using Server version: 10.4.20-MariaDB

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`;` is used to indicate the end of a query and should not be used in between.
Also always use `IS` to compare with `null` instead of `=`

```
SET user_games.result = 
                  CASE WHEN games.winner IS NULL OR games.winner = '' then NULL
                       WHEN user_games.pick = games.winner then 'W' 
                       ELSE 'L'
                  END;
```

Comment: Thank you! It is halfway working; however, I'm still seeing the user_games.pick column getting updated with 'L' when the games.winner is NULL.. it is empty, would it be '' instead of NULL?

Comment: Thank you so much @juergend!!! It's working perfectly now. The columns were '' instead of NULL. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @juergend I don't know why you have a negative score for the solution. You replied first and updated your response with details that addressed the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is the query below solve your issues ?

```
update  a
set a.result = 
CASE 
    WHEN a.pick = b.winner then 'W'
    WHEN b.winner = NULL then NULL
    ELSE 'L'
END
from user_games  a
LEFT JOIN games b ON a.game_key = b.game_id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**: you have to write a specific condition for `L` because in ELSE it can be updated in many conditions. Also, use `IS NULL`  to check the `NULL` value in the column instead of `= NULL`.

```
UPDATE user_games 
LEFT JOIN games ON user_games.game_key = games.game_id 
SET user_games.result = 
            CASE 
                WHEN user_games.pick = games.winner THEN 'W'
                WHEN games.winner IS NOT NULL AND user_games.pick <> games.winner THEN 'L'
                ELSE NULL
            END;
```